# How to extract tagged text from a text file using a regex?

Tags: python, regex

For a class, I need to extract everything that comes between the element `<seg>` ... `</seg>` and I'm trying to do this via Python instead of wasting hours doing this by hand (it's well over 400 lines). What I have right now in ways of code is this (a code that I found online and changed a little so that it doesn't print the line number):

```
import re                           
err_occur = [] 
pattern = re.compile(r"<seg>(.*)</seg>")
try:
    with open ('corpus.txt', 'rt') as in_file:
        for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file):
            if pattern.search(line) != None:
                err_occur.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
        for linenum, line in err_occur:
            print(line, sep='')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Input file not found.")
```

The only problem I have with this is that it prints the `<seg>` and `</seg>` in the results, which I don't want to happen. I've tried to create groups (which you can see in my usage of parentheses in the pattern variable) but I have no idea how to manipulate the code to return just group 1 (I've tried many different ways).

Comment: What is group 1?

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: Sometime back i also asked the question on the same lines. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851040/python-identify-the-missing-character-and-replace-with-na. If this helps let us know, otherwise please post a sample of text file and will come up with a answer for you.

Comment: My input would be something like "... <seg> Hello world. </seg>" and my expected output is "Hello World" without the <seg> elements. I see that my question got a little messed up formatting wise, whoops!

Comment: Group 1 is the .* inside the parentheses of the regular expression I'm searching for

Comment: Collect the return value from `pattern.search`, it is a `match` object with a `.groups()` method. (or `None` if it does not match)

Comment: If you're going to be doing this a lot you could take a look at the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that will print all the tagged text in each line without the tags:

The important modification was changing your regex from `(r"<seg>(.*)</seg>"` to `r"<seg>(.*?)</seg>"`—note the added `?` after the `*`. This is called making it "non-greedy" so it *doesn't* match as much of the remaining text as possible (the default "greedy" mode). This is discussed in greater detail in the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) section of Python's online documentation.

Another significant change, regex-wise, was to use [`pattern.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) *instead* of [`pattern.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search).

I also removed all the parts of the code dealing with line numbers since you mentioned you weren't interest in that information.

```
import re

err_occur = []
pattern = re.compile(r"<seg>(.*?)</seg>")
input_filename = 'corpus.txt'

try:
    with open(input_filename, 'rt') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            matches = pattern.findall(line)
            if matches:
                for match in matches:
                    err_occur.append(match)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Input file %r not found." % input_filename)

for tagged in err_occur:
    print(tagged)
```

Comment: Arie G.: Good to hear. Note the limitation that the tagged text _within_ a single line—which means that tagged text that spans multiple lines won't be detected. Fixing that requires a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `positive lookbehind` and a `positive lookahead`. The `<seg>` and `<\seg>` in your regex consumes some text so you see them in your results, but the lookahead and lookbehind just checks if `</seg>` and `<seg>` are there respectively without consuming any characters. It only matches those strings.

**Tl;dr:**  lookahead and lookbehind matches **string** in 
`<seg>string</seg>` and not the tags.

So your regex should be like `(?<=<seg>).*(?=</seg>)`, this should be fine.

There is some documantation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it's still showing the <seg> opening and closing elements, so the results are all <seg>string</seg> instead of just the string

Comment: can you share some of the documents you are trying to filter, ArieG

Comment: For example, this is part of the XML/TXT document: 
<seg>ben on attend on attend qui normalement </seg>
</u>
</annotationBlock>
<annotationBlock end="#T2" start="#T1" who="spk2" xml:id="au1">
<u>
<seg>ben ¤P1¤ </seg>
</u>
</annotationBlock>
<annotationBlock end="#T3" start="#T2" who="spk4" xml:id="au2">
<u>
<seg>non </seg>
</u>
</annotationBlock>
<annotationBlock end="#T4" start="#T3" who="spk3" xml:id="au3">
<u>
<seg>/tu les as eu(e)s,***/ </seg>
</u>
</annotationBlock>
--I'm trying to get just the text in between <seg>

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for this.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your input)
print soup.findAll("seg")[0].renderContents()
```

Also the regex can be:

```
import re
print re.findall("<seg>(.*?)</seg>", your input)
```

http://tpcg.io/B6h2So